# Transmit data with Jetpack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Looking for a more elegant way to transmit data with Jetpack

Now I am passing the data as follows:

```
override fun onListItemClick(itemIndex: Int, itemCode: String) {
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString(KEY_TARGET_GUID, (adapter.getItem(itemIndex) as Target).guid)
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.target_edit, bundle)
    }
```

And get it in another fragment smth like this:

```
private val targetGuid: String
        get() = arguments?.getString(KEY_TARGET_GUID, "") ?: ""
```

I watched the guys at google do it in [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#7), but in his example they created class `FlowStepFragmentArgs`, and it is voluminous

```
data class FlowStepFragmentArgs(val flowStepNumber: Int = 2) : NavArgs {
    fun toBundle(): Bundle {
        val result = Bundle()
        result.putInt("flowStepNumber", this.flowStepNumber)
        return result
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun fromBundle(bundle: Bundle): FlowStepFragmentArgs {
            bundle.setClassLoader(FlowStepFragmentArgs::class.java.classLoader)
            val __flowStepNumber : Int
            if (bundle.containsKey("flowStepNumber")) {
                __flowStepNumber = bundle.getInt("flowStepNumber")
            } else {
                __flowStepNumber = 2
            }
            return FlowStepFragmentArgs(__flowStepNumber)
        }
    }
}
```

**Q**: How can I transfer data beautifully in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Navigation Architecture you can do it as :- 
Let you have declared fragments in your navigation.xml file as :-

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_a"
    android:name="com.example.FragmentA">
    <action android:id="@+id/action_item_click"
        app:destination="@id/fragment_b" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_b"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentB">
    <argument android:name="id" app:argType="string" android:defaultValue="sample data" />
</fragment>
```

Note :-

1. **A class is created for each destination where an action originates.** The name of this class is the name of the originating
   destination, appended with the word "**Directions**".
2. **This class has a method for each action defined in the originating destination.**

So for **FragmentA** class it will be generated as **FragmentADirections** eg. -

```
override fun onListItemClick(itemIndex: Int, itemCode: String) {
    findNavController().navigate(FragmentADirections.actionItemClick("Pass YOUR_STRING"))
}
```

Note :-

1. **A class is created for the receiving destination**. The name of this class is the name of the destination, appended with the word "**Args**".

And for **FragmentB** class it will be generated as you can get data as **FragmentBArgs** eg:-

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    // do what you want with this id
    arguments?.let {bundle->
       val id = FragmentBArgs.fromBundle(bundle).id
    }
              // OR you can do also as
    // val id = arguments?.getString("id").orEmpty()
}
```

For more details please take reference of https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are really only 2 options to pass data using Jetpack Navigation.

1) Using Bundle. Here I find `budnleOf(x to y)` function really handy

```
    val targetGuid = adapter.getItem(itemIndex) as Target).guid)
    val bundle = bundleOf(KEY_TARGET_GUID, targetGuid)
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.target_edit, bundle)
```

2) By defining arguments of your destination inside your navigation graph. Which will generate code. Assuming you `R.id.target_edit` is a fragment:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/target_edit"
    android:name="com.example.TargetEditFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_target_edit">
    <argument
        android:name="targetGuid"
        android:defaultValue="@null"
        app:argType="com.example.Target"
        app:nullable="true"/>
 </fragment>
```

Then in your `TargetEditFragment`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  val targetGuid =
    arguments?.let { TargetEditFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).targetGuid }
}
```